# Number of states in Z2 gauge theory on a finite square lattice

Tags: quantum-field-theory, many-body, topological-field-theory

In Wen's Quantum Field theory of many body systems, on page 254, it discusses Z2 gauge theory, and states that

> Count the number of states in the Z2 gauge theory on a finite square
>   lattice. We assume that the lattice has a periodic boundary condition
>   in both directions (i.e the lattice forms a torus). If the lattice has
>   $N_{site}$ sites, then it has $2N_{site}$ nearest neighbor links.

This is very confusing. If I take a square lattice, I see that each point has two nearest neighbors. However, if I extend the lattice into a 3rd dimension, I would also expect nearest neighbors behind and after the lattice "slice", giving me 4N nearest neighbors. I was told that it has to do with combinatorics and the prefactor for feynman diagrams, but I'm wondering if there isn't a simpler explanation. And if there isn't, where can I learn this type of information?

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In three dimensions, there are *three* nearest-neighbor links per site on a cubic lattice: in the $\hat x$, $\hat y$, and $\hat z$ directions. You don’t count the one in the $-\hat z$ direction, just like you don’t fount the ones in the $-\hat x$ and $-\hat y$ directions. They are the positive-direction links for neighboring sites, and you would be double-counting.

Comment: Wouldn’t this lead to 3N nearest neighbors instead of 2N?

Comment: $N$ in one dimension; $2N$ in two dimensions; $3N$ in three dimensions. You don’t get $4N$ in three dimensions like you thought.

Comment: And this has nothing to do with combinatorics or Feynman diagrams. It’s just geometry.

Comment: Hmm okay so when it says the lattice forms a torus it means 2D? But isn’t that increasing the dimension by going from a 2D lattice to a 3D torus?

Comment: I’m trying to reconcile what you said with what the text says

Comment: A square where the right side is identified with the left side, and the bottom with the top, is topologically a 2-torus. You are envisioning a 2-torus as a 2D donut-shaped surface embedded in 3D space. Forget about the 3D embedding space and just think about the topology of the 2D surface.

Comment: If this makes no sense to you, read a bit about topology. You probably have not been introduced to topological thinking before.

Comment: Ah okay this makes sense... I need to read some topology